# Some Users receiving more junk spam mail

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, spam, spamassassin

To start: we are using exchange 2010 with spam assassin.
Some of our users are experiencing a rise in junk spam emails for about two weeks now. Most of these junk emails even get to the normal inbox without being classified as junk.

These users have no mailing list in common, that is why we are puzzled. 
Our guess is that these users used their corporate email addresses to sign up on some site or petition or something like that.

Since we are receiving a lot of "feedback" from these users which takes up too much time lately is there anything we could do except block the senders email address and IP?

Every idea is much appreciated!

Comment: What, besides SpamAssassin, are you already doing to reduce the amount of junk mail? Are you doing greylisting? DNSBLs?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Nothing else that I am aware of.  It also seems that most of our users do no seem to have this problem only 5-7 users are receiving this huge amount of spam. How do I apply DNSBLs on MS Exchange 2010?

Comment: *"How do I apply DNSBLs on MS Exchange 2010?"* would probably be a decent *separate* question, if it hasn't been asked already (make sure to search first, and share what you learned from those searches).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling probably going to do that. thank you!

Comment: Anti-Spam appliances do provide decent filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the junk mails header to see if these emails were send from specific IP address, we can block it with Transport rule on Exhcange hub server.

We can also add the ip to the block list with the command:

Add-IPBlockListProvider

Please refer to:

http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/windows/exchange/2010/how_to_add_an_ip_block_list.htm

What's the SCL value of these junk emails? And check if the messgae subject and content with same words then create a transport rule and block them.

For your question apply DNSBLs on MS Exchange 2010, as we know different DNSBLs for different purposes, you should deside with to use.

Please refer to: https://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage#201

Hope it helps.